# How to add custom pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a word press site **hello.com**.

I need to add a custom page to the site , so that it will display the contents from this page.

it may  an php, or html page like *welcome.php* or *welcome.html*.

And it should be  able to take ***hello.com/welcome*** on the browser.

How i can do it?

Comment: Do you want to add a Wordpress "Page" or another file (with possibly PHP code)? For Wordpress pages, you just use the administration; for other files, the simplest way is to just add the file (put a welcome.php file in the WP directory). A more advanced way is to program a plugin with some custom path.

Comment: Just place a file called *welcome* onto the server. Configure your webserver to signal the correct content-type for it and you're done. Just standard file-serving via HTTP.

Comment: Actually i created a welcome.php file and uploaded to the themes folder and i am trying to call the page by hello.com/welcome.But its not working

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ftp access? I assume you are not looking to simply create a page. If you have ftp access to the site you can upload a php or html file. This will not add the page to the Wordpress database but does not require installing any plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But it will display only the content that we added on the admin side, right?.I need to display the content  from my original page welcome.php or welcome.html (its a physicial page)

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer for my question.

1)First create a page say welcome.php , then add  like

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: welcome
*/
?>
```

Upload the page to the selected theme folder

2) Then go to  admin side and create a new page and select welcome from its template option.

3) Take the url of  created page, then it will load the content from the 'welcome.php' page